# Solving $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$ given bounds

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions does $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$$ have, given that $x_1, x_2,$ and $x_3$ are nonnegative integers with $x_1 ≤ 3, x_2 ≤ 4,$ and $x_3 ≤ 6$?

---

I wasn't quite sure how to deal with the bounds given

Comment: Hint: Let $y_1=3-x_1$, $y_2=4-x_2$, and $y_3=6-x_3$

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks!